# How to control my telephone via Mobile/IoT?

Tags: smart-home

I have a telephone at home which is an electronic instrument connected via wire.

It is not a cordless but a corded phone comes with a telephone wire.

Is there a way to lock or unlock it via mobile or IoT? A telephone code can be used to lock the phone. However if I forget to do it then how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you could add a relay that disconnect the telephone wires and control that with a IoT device or ex. a Arduino with a a GSM module like SIM800/900 and control the relay.

Comment: Of course doing this is dangerous, just cutting the phone off means it can not be used to make emergency calls or to even receive calls.

Comment: Everything where you do stuff without realizing the consequence are more or less dangerous.

Comment: yes, that correct..Matsk, what are your comments on the same?

Comment: The OP ask how he can lock the phone remotely and depending of the "lock" mechanism, software with emergency function anyway or if it is of the type where you lock the phone and there is no emergency break through, mthat is my reason for asking in the comment to OP, what kind of lock?